# How to Rotate an element Counterclockwise

Tags: css, html, rotation

I know we can rotate an element anticlockwise by using negative sign

`transform : rotate(-20deg);`

But this is only for x-axis. I want to rotate element along the y-axis. i tried

`transform : rotateY(-20deg);`

this doesn't works it rotate the element in same direction as we are using:

`transform : rotateY(20deg);`

i am searching for an answer for half-hour . please help.

Comment: Without seeing what it is you are trying to achieve it's hard to help, Your Y rotattion should work but perhaps it's not showing what you think it should. - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/QEAXkV

Comment: basically my question is   `transform:rotateY(20deg)` and `transform:rotateY(-20deg)` both rotate the element in same direction. i want to rotate in oppposite direction direction . please try it then answer.

Comment: You need to make a demo of the problem you are having. Rotate Y will NOT have the same effect as Rotate X.

Comment: its fine i just want to confirm that `rotateY`  has no effect of neagative sign.thanks for help

Comment: Off course the negative sign makes a difference, it rotates it a different direction.

Answer (score 0):

When you used `transform : rotate(-20deg);`, you said that it was `only for x-axis.`

So your question is: `I want to rotate element along the y-axis.`If you meant that you wanted to rotate your div vertically, then the code below might help:

```css
.rotate-vertically {
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  background:red;
  padding:10px;
  text-align:center;
   transition: all 1.0s linear;
   
}

.rotate-vertically:hover {
  transform:rotateX(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="rotate-vertically">Hover me!
</div>
```

More information [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transform/)

Answer (score -1):

Why doesn't it? It does. Or do you want to stretch the element? Then `transform:scale()` would help you.

```css
div{
  transform: scale(2,1);
  margin-left:200px;
}
```

```html
<div>text</div>
```

(adding also the left margin, since scaling pushes the element off the screen)